# Microsoft Graph API get all user messages for tenant in single API call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to get all user messages (emails) for a tenant in a single API call?  This would be for a daemon app with admin consent not logging in on behalf of a user.

```
such as:
"endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/messages"

instead of:
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages
```

Or is it required to get a list of active users first and make API calls for each user id to get messages individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you could not get all user's messages directly with the [single API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). As you said, you could [get a list of users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) then loop to call this API by the user's object id.

There is a [sample](https://tech.xenit.se/querying-microsoft-graph-with-powershell-the-easy-way/) as a reference about looping to query using Powershell.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the answer I was looking for, as well as thank you for the great resource.  Very helpful.

Comment: The documentation of that "single API" lacks real world examples of getting messages for a user by ID or principal.